# Windows 10: Cloning Boot Drive: What to do now

Tags: windows-10, cloning

I cloned a 1TB boot drive to another 2 TB drive.

[image: Disk Management]

(1) How can I format Disk 0 to use for data?

(2) Disk 1 has 932.05GB unallocated. What to do with them?

Comment: First make sure you *can* boot from the cloned drive. Disconnect or disable the other one in the firmware (UEFI) and adjust the boot order accordingly. Then, and only then you can do with both whatever you want, like extending the adjacent to the unallocated space partition to use all of that and format the other drive as you see fit. Don't ask for opinions because off-topic. If you're looking for a discussion please post in a forum, not at a Q&A website.

Comment: He seems to already be booted from Disk 1 (as that one has the C: on it)

Comment: One question per post please. Read the Help section to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1 - Format the 1 TB Drive:

You need to delete all partitions on the drive and format/add one big partition to use for data.

Disk Management might not allow you to delete some of those system partitions, so you will be better helped by using a 3rd party partition management utility, like [**MiniTool Partition Wizard**](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/) (or if you're comfortable with command line tools, then Windows' `DISKPART` would let you do it.)

You need to **Delete** the 5 partitions on the drive > Create one new (NTFS) partition.

### 2 - Extend C: Partition on 2 TB Drive:

Right-click on the C: partition in Disk Management and choose **Extend Volume**, add all the available space and click **Finish**.

If Disk Management doesn't allow you to extend the C: volume, you can also do it with a 3rd party tool as mentioned above.

Comment: Very clear answer. Working on it now.

Comment: I now installed MiniTool Partition Wizard. This is the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/weJiT8P What to do now?

Comment: For 2, I tried Disk Manager but "extend volume" is greyed out.

Comment: For 1: Right click on **Disk 1** and choose ***Delete all partitions***. Then click ***Apply***.

Comment: For 2: It happens (due to the fact that the unallocated spaces isn't next to the C: partition.) So this as well in MiniTool Partition Wizard.

Comment: Right click on Disk 1 and choose Delete all partitions. Then click Apply-> done

Comment: This is the current situation https://imgur.com/a/hBldsnq Shall I just extend C:(NTFS) as much as possible with "Extend Partition"? Or shall I keep some partition?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Rs7Gyft shows there is an option to extend to Recovery. Shall one do it?

Comment: For 1: Right click on the unallocated in Disk 1 and do Create. For 2: Leave the other partitions alone unless you know that you don't need the space (which you don't).

Comment: So I set assigned E to disk 1 for 1. Is it everything that needs to be done for now?

Comment: Yes. (Click **Apply** after ***Create*** if not done yet.)

Comment: So I can now restart the PC. Thank you!

Comment: I restarted and it did not make these changes. https://imgur.com/a/toHXJfc

Comment: Did you press Apply after each step? Put a screenshot of Disk Management and MiniTool Partition Wizard now.

Comment: Also you now booted from the 1 TB drive, not the 2 TB drive. So before deleting the 1 TB drive you'll need to reboot and start from the 2 TB drive (it'd be good if you shut of the PC and switch the two drives where they're connected on the motherboard.)

Comment: @YisroelTech It might be prudent for the first step to be to physically remove the 1 TB drive so that it cannot accidentally be damaged while trying to get the 2 TB drive into the desired state (i.e. with a larger partition for C:).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I don't see how actions on one drive can cause issue in the other one. Of course people can click wrong things, but if you are afraid of that, then they can anyhow damage/delete both separately... I agree that it's more cautious, the question is how cautious one really needs to be.

Comment: I was able to fix them. I think it is fine now. Thank you very much.